# Memory Violation Dynamically Appending to Methods at runtime

Tags: c#, methods, dynamic, reflection, runtime

**Disclaimer:** I'm doing this for learning purposes. This is not going to be used in code.

I'm trying to understand how method table are structure for generics, I want to dynamically appending to methods at runtime.   I found a very useful [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method) reference for getting me started.

I have a simple controller which I'm using as a test to verify my methods are swapping:

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    static ValuesController() {
        var methodToReplace = typeof(ValuesController).GetMethod(nameof(ValuesController.Seven),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

        var methodToAppend = typeof(ValuesController).GetMethod(nameof(ValuesController.Eight),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

        new Initializer(methodToReplace, methodToAppend);
    }

    [HttpGet("Seven")]
    public int Seven(string id)
    {
        return 7;
    }

    [HttpGet("Eight")]
    public int Eight(string id)
    {
        return 8;
    }
}
```

I have a class `Initializer` which is in charge of handling appending to the method.

```
public class Initializer
{
    public Initializer(MethodInfo methodToReplace, MethodInfo methodToAppend)
    {
        var dummyMethod = typeof(Initializer).GetMethod(nameof(Dummy),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

        var proxyMethod = typeof(Initializer).GetMethod(nameof(Proxy),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

        var appendedMethod = typeof(Initializer).GetMethod(nameof(Appended),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

        dummyMethod.OneWayReplace(methodToReplace);
        methodToReplace.OneWayReplace(proxyMethod);
        appendedMethod.OneWayReplace(methodToAppend);
    }

    public int Proxy(string id)
    {
        Dummy(id);
        return Appended(id);
    }

    public int Dummy(string id)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public int Appended(string id)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And then I have the Extensions which I've obtained from the original stackoverflow question:

```
public static class InjectionExtensions
{
    // Note: This method replaces methodToReplace with methodToInject
    // Note: methodToInject will still remain pointing to the same location
    public static unsafe MethodReplacementState OneWayReplace(this MethodInfo methodToReplace, MethodInfo methodToInject)
    {
        //#if DEBUG
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToReplace.MethodHandle);
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToInject.MethodHandle);
        //#endif
        MethodReplacementState state;

        IntPtr tar = methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value;
        var inj = methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value + 8;

        if (!methodToReplace.IsVirtual)
            tar += 8;
        else
        {
            var index = (int)(((*(long*)tar) >> 32) & 0xFF);
            var classStart = *(IntPtr*)(methodToReplace.DeclaringType.TypeHandle.Value + (IntPtr.Size == 4 ? 40 : 64));
            tar = classStart + IntPtr.Size * index;
        }
#if DEBUG
        tar = *(IntPtr*)tar + 1;
        inj = *(IntPtr*)inj + 1;
        state.Location = tar;
        state.OriginalValue = new IntPtr(*(int*)tar);

        *(int*)tar = *(int*)inj + (int)(long)inj - (int)(long)tar;
        return state;

#else
        state.Location = tar;
        state.OriginalValue = *(IntPtr*)tar;
        * (IntPtr*)tar = *(IntPtr*)inj;
        return state;
#endif
    }
}
```

**Note:** Using the current setup everything works fine.  However, the second I change the `Initializer` class to be a generic class `Initializer<T>` I get a memory violation:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

My guess is that either the `methodToReplace.DeclaringType.TypeHandle.Value` calculation differs for generics,  Or since the compiler is the one who generates the generic class it written to protected memory?

**Edit**
I've found more information I need to prepare the method properly when using generic parameters e.g:

```
RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToInject.MethodHandle, new[] { typeof(T).TypeHandle });
```

However there are still a few more pieces to the puzzle to get this working.

**Edit**

There are a few open source project's such as [harmony](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony) that do similar things,  However it looks like their emitting their own assemblies.  While I've considered the option, I would still prefer to understand how I method tables work with generics

How can I append to methods that reside in generic classes?

Comment: `DeclaringType` will be generic type in this case, right? Do you need to rebuild the method signature like in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)?

Comment: @timur,  the DeclaringType is generic, however, the method has no reference to the generic type.   Generics clearly have some affects on the method swap.  But I don't have enough information to understand, my guess is the declaring type modifies the address calculation of the class start.  So I'm writing to protected memory because I'm overwriting a memory barrier.  I'm a bit confused on what you mean by rebuilding the method signature, I'm not invoking the method though reflection, I'm just swapping the pointers

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have already seen: [Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method)

I have adapted some of those methods in my own project @ https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma_core/blob/master/Concepts/Classes/MethodHelper.cs

I think the problem is that if your are running with the Debugger Attached then you need to also handle the portion of the logic which is currently defined by `IFDEF` at compilation time and replace that with an `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` although the offsets calculations (to jump over the debugger injected code) will probably have to change depending on various things like the version of the framework in use.

See https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma_core/blob/master/Concepts/Classes/MethodHelper.cs#L35

This works for me in .Net Core 3.1 when the debugger IS NOT attached and I am running in Release mode, when running in Debug mode with or without the debugger attached or in Release mode with the debugger attached I receive different exceptions. (In debug I receive Arithmetic Overflow, while in release I receive Execution Engine Exception).

Furthermore this only works until the JIT Tiering kicks in, if I run the method a 2nd time without the debugger attached I am getting a Internal CLR Error.

I believe this has to do with the code injected by the debugger when attached and to be honest I am not up to do date on exactly what the debugger is injecting when attached.

I would make a simplified repo of the problem and ask a question @ https://github.com/dotnet/runtime if you need this to work with the debugger attached and I am sure someone there will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm usually running in debug mode, with the debugger attached, The code I posted works fine it's only when I switch the Initalizer to be generic in which it breaks or if I try to swap a generic method, I think it's because of how generics are done under the hood.  Are you saying this will work in release mode?

Comment: It might at least the first time.